# Can I reduce my file size, by generelising code for multible worksheets in one code module?

Tags: excel, vba, activex, filesize

I've been working on an excel file to streamline purchasing from different African farms.

The order sheet is nearly finished, but I stumbled upon an annoying issue. I'm left with a 19MB file.

There are two active X buttons ("+" and "-") per worksheet. 8 worksheets in total. One for every day of the week + one that collects and adds up quantities in a "program" worksheet.

Button "+" adds a specified row (see code below)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("FRIDAY").Select ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="ORDER"

Dim varUserInput As Variant  varUserInput = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", _   "What Row?")  If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub

Rows("49:49").Select Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

RowNum = varUserInput
Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Insert Shift:=x1Down
Rows(RowNum + 1 & ":" & RowNum + 1).Copy Range("A" & RowNum)
Range(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).ClearContents
Range("A48:K48").Select

Selection.Copy
Range(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-105
Range("B1:K1").Select
Sheets("FRIDAY").Select ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="ORDER"

End Sub
```

The Button "-" deletes one row (and adds one to keep the same layout as below:)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Sheets("FRIDAY").Select ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="ORDER"

Dim varUserInput As Variant  varUserInput = InputBox("Enter Row Number that you want to delete", _   "What Row?")  If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub

RowNum = varUserInput
Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Delete Shift:=x1Down
Rows("49:49").Select Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp

Range("A48:K48").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A49:K49").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-105
Range("B1:K1").Select
Sheets("FRIDAY").Select ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="ORDER"

End Sub
```

Additionally, there is one macro is the myworksheet module that keeps the layout nice and tidy.

```
Public Sub HideAllButPrintArea()
Dim xPrintRng As Range
Dim xFirstRng As Range
Dim xLastRng As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.ActiveSheet
    .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    If .PageSetup.PrintArea <> "" Then
        Set xPrintRng = .Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea)
    Else
        Set xPrintRng = .UsedRange
    End If

    Set xFirstRng = xPrintRng.Cells(1)
    Set xLastRng = xPrintRng.Cells(xPrintRng.Count)

    If xFirstRng.Row > 1 Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), xFirstRng(-0, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If xFirstRng.Column > 1 Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), xFirstRng(1, 0)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If

    If xLastRng.Row < .Rows.Count Then
        .Range(xLastRng(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If xLastRng.Column < .Columns.Count Then
        .Range(xLastRng(1, 2), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Hidden = 
True
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

How can I keep the same button on each worksheet, whilst still reducing my file-size to preferably <8MB?

Comment: If this is all code you have in the workbook - it's not the reason of workbook's huge size.

Comment: As @VitaliyPrushak wrote above. But besides that your code is terrible because of use macro recorder. All "scroll" lines should be deleted. And type in SO search window: "how to avoid using select and activate" and read about "fully qualifying range vba" (i don't know how tu put a links here). This code will fail one day.